# Questions about book

Tags: romance

So i want to write a book. It would probably be in the romance section (well, obviously). A short summary I guess would be a pan girl moves into a bi girl's town. They do a bunch of stuff together (and their parents just think they're really good friends) and i guess the bi girl would end up confessing? I sort of need a conflict, and I think it would probably be character vs self with the bi girl (she's the main protagonist) and about something like anxiety. Is this good? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jessica and welcome to Writers.  We're a little different from other sites; we're not a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  We can help you with questions about writing technique, publishing, plot structure, and stuff like that, but we can't help with "what to write".  Please take a look at our short [tour].  Can you [edit] this question to be about the genre or about introducing conflict, rather than just asking what you should write?  Thanks.

Comment: While the edit is good in principle, there are a few major problems with it. Mainly, the fact that it basically changes the question into a *different* question, which is something we try hard to avoid in edits. [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/editing) The edited version is basically asking for us to critique an idea, which is off topic as both critique and being primarily opinion-based. This question as it stands also has an answer already (which has been voted on), which further restricts the kind of edits that can be made.

Comment: Even if this question can be reopened, the odds that we'll be able to get any useful clarification from the person who posted the question almost four years ago (and who hasn't been seen on the site since then) seem rather slim. Hannah Kelley, I have rolled back your edit, **but** if you're interested in such a question, feel free to post a new one! Do make sure though that it fits within [our subject scope](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

In a typical romance, the usual conflict is that something is keeping the lovers apart. It could be family, competing obligations, character flaws in the lovers, initial distaste for each other, cultural views of who is allowed to love whom, natural disasters, or any other conditions or events that keep them apart.

The story is usually about how the lovers struggle with the things that keep them apart, and how they come together in the end.

I don't know whether pan/bi romance stories follow a similar pattern.